# Retrigger event after clicking away

Tags: jquery

I have this code that prevents a click event first time I click and resolve second time. But if I click on item 2 and back on item 1 it does not prevent the click event. I want It to start over if I click outside of an item.

JS

```
   $('.dropdown').each(function () {

        $(this).find('a').on('click.menuClick', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).parent().addClass('dropDownClass');
            $(this).off("click.menuClick");

        });
    });
```

html

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is a fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/gt1zhcyc/4/

Comment: try replacing     `$(this).unbind(".menuClick");` with `    `$(this).off("click.menuClick");`

Comment: That did not help.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. one comment, use of each is not needed here. $(".dropdown a").on ... Beside code works as intended, binds to event, unbinds when event is fired.

Comment: I want this to happen. If I click on item 1 once then another element then item 1 again I still want prevent default. it must only go to the url if i click on it twice in a row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple logic around this: instead of relying on `.on()` and `.off()` to bind/unbind your custom namespaced click event, you can use `.on()` + storing the clicked state in the `.data()` object for your anchor element.

Let's say we store your clicked state with the key of `hasClicked` in the element. When your `<a>` element is clicked, you simply check if `.data('hasClicked')` is falsy: it will evaluate to false when it is undefined, or it has been set to `false`. If it is falsy, you set it to `true`, which stores the state that "Hey, I've been clicked on once before!". Here, you can also reset the clicked state of its siblings:

```
if (!$(this).data('hasClicked')) {
  // Store state
  $(this).data('hasClicked', true);

  // Remove clicked state other anchor elements that is not self
  $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('a')
    .not(this)
    .data('hasClicked', false);

  // ...
} else {
  // Clicked the second time, we reset the clicked state
  $(this).data('hasClicked', false);

  // ...
}
```

The second trick you want to bring out is **clicking outside these elements to reset the clicked state**. You can simply rely on event bubbling: when a click event is fired from your link, you stop it from propagating up to the document. Meanwhile, you set up an identical listener on the document object to catch the click event (which must have emitted outside your anchor element). When this event is caught, you forcibly reset all the clicked states back to `false`:

```
$(document).on('click.menuClick', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown a').data('hasClicked', false);
});
```

The logic below encompasses the answer described above, by combining both logic:

```js
$(function() {
  // Listen to click event on <a>
  $('.dropdown a').on('click.menuClick', function(e) {

    // TODO: Remove this, only for testing
    e.preventDefault();

    // Prevent click event from bubbling
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Check if element has been clicked before
    // If never clicked before, we prevent action and store state
    if (!$(this).data('hasClicked')) {
      // Store state
      $(this).data('hasClicked', true);
      $(this).addClass('hasClicked');
      console.log('Clicked the first time');
      
      // Remove clicked state other anchor elements that is not self
      $(this).closest('.dropdown').find('a')
        .not(this)
        .data('hasClicked', false)
        .removeClass('hasClicked');
    } else {
      $(this).data('hasClicked', false).removeClass('hasClicked');
      console.log('Second clikc, already clicked once');
    }

  });

  // Listen to bubbling click event on document
  $(document).on('click.menuClick', function(e) {
    $('.dropdown a').data('hasClicked', false).removeClass('hasClicked');
    console.log('Click detected outside, resetting hasClicked state');
  });

});
```

```css
.hasClicked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="google.com">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="yahoo.com">item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I get the achieved effect that if clicked twice on the same element it will go to the url else it wont. And this must reset every time you click away

Comment: @Newcoma The logic already does it for you? Just use `window.location.href` when the state is clicked so it will redirect on second click.

Comment: If I put  window.location.href = 'google.com' beneath console.log('Already clicked once'); it does not reset when i click away.

Comment: @Newcoma If you also want to reset it, then add `$(this).data('hasClicked', false)` before redirecting.

Comment: Yeah it works. What if I have the class="dropdown" on both li elements ?